# Will a substring of another string prevent the parent string from being garbage collected?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

```
String samplel = "ToBeGarbageCollected";
String sample2 = samplel.substring(0, 1);
samplel = null;
```

I know substring internally will keep a reference for original String.

But by explicitly defining `samplel` as `null`, will sample1 and sample2 be available for garbage Collection?

I remember seeing somewhere if a parent object is explicitly set to `null` all child values are available for garbage collection. Will this hold good for the above?
I am just curious if this the parent child relationship scenario? If not, will this cause `sample1` or `sample2` to be available for garbage collection?

```
String samplel = "ToBeGarbageCollected";
String sample2 = new String(samplel .substring(0, 1));
samplel  = null;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First thing to say is that garbage collection doesn't happen immediately.  So assigning `null` to anything does not / cannot *cause* garbage collection.  What is *may* do is to cause an object to become *unreachable* ... and that will make it a potential candidate for garbage collection in a future GC run.

---

Now to your specific examples.

**Important Note:** the following *only* applies to older JVMs; i.e. Java 7 update 5 and earlier.  In Java 7 update 6, they changed `String.substring()` so that the target string and resulting substring DO NOT share the backing array.  This eliminates the potential storage leak issue with `substring`.

---

The `substring` method doesn't put a reference to the original String in the new String.  What it actually does is save a reference to the original String's backing array; i.e the array that holds the characters.

But having said that, assigning `null` to `samplel` is not sufficient to make the state of the entire original string unreachable.  The original String's *entire* backing array will be remain reachable ... and that means it won't be a candidate for garbage collection.

But there is another complication.  You set `sample1` to a String literal, and the String object that represents a String literal is *always* reachable (unless the entire class gets unloaded!)

> But by explicitly defining samplel as null, will sample1 and sample2 be available for garbage Collection?

The original `sample1` object will remain fully reachable, and `sample2` will remain be reachable unless that variable goes out of scope.

If `sample1` had not been a literal and there were no other references to it, then the answer would be different.  The `sample1` object would be unreachable, but its backing array would still be reachable via `sample2`.

---

In your second example, copying the substring causes a new String to be created.  And it is guaranteed that the new String won't share the backing array with the original String and the temporary substring.  In that case, assigning `null` is unnecessary.

> Will now both sample1 and sample2 be available for garbage Collection?

The answer is the same as for the above for the case where `sample1` is a literal.

If `sample1` is not a literal and there are no other references to it, then `sample1` and the temporary substring would now be unreachable.

---

> I just want to know where does String constructor be helpful.

In theory it will be.

In practice it depends on whether the references are still reachable when the GC eventually gets around to looking ... and also on whether the Strings in question are large enough and numerous enough to have a significant impact on memory usage.

And in practice, that precondition is *usually* NOT satisfied and creating a fresh String like that *usually* does NOT help.

Comment: His use of the terminology 'available for garbage collection' is correct: it is clear that the O.P. knows garbage collection doesn't happen immediately, and that this fact does not impact the actual question, right?

Comment: @NathanielFord - It is not clear to me that he understands what those words mean.  I have chosen to answer the question in a way that doesn't assume that understanding.  And also so that other people who missed / didn't understand that point can ALSO understand the answer.

Comment: @Suraj - if there are threads accessing or able to access an object, then it is reachable.  That is essentially what reachability means.

Comment: @StephenC - Okay but my doubt is why is it said by explicitly setting the parent value as null the child will also be garbage collected. Does this hold good even if child is accessed byt live threads.??

Comment: @Suraj - The *"it is said"* is an incorrect characterization of what is happening.  Explicitly setting a reference variable to null only changes the reachability status of the child if there are no other reachable variables holding that reference.  That includes local variables of live threads ... and anything reachable from them.

Comment: In java 1.7 update 6, substring no longer uses the backing array of the original string. Discussion on Reddit http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/1qw73v/til_oracle_changed_the_internal_string/

Answer (score 2):

Remember that in Java `String` is immutable. In this case, `sample1` will be discarded, but `sample2` never pointed to `sample1`: it pointed to a separately held immutable string in the JVM that was created at the latest when `substring` was called.

When you set `sample1` to null, the memory it pointed to became available for garbage collection (assuming no other strings held the same value and no other variables were pointed at that location). When you use the `new` keyword (or implicitly do so through the assignment of a primitive) new memory is allocated on the heap (usually; again, strings are immutable and share the same memory). If no pointers (read: any named variables) point to a given location of memory, it is available for garbage collection.

Remember: in any case where there are no references to an object, it becomes available for garbage collection. Objects are not defined by the variable names assigned to them, but rather are locations in memory, and the variable names act as pointers (references) to those objects. Strings are somewhat different because they are immutable, and the JVM may opt not to garbage collect for reasons independent of references to them.

Comment: So you mean to say . If no threads are accessing sample1 in both the scenarios its available for GC.???

Comment: Yes, but realize that `Strings`, being immutable, are handled differently than a normal object. The JVM may not garbage collect them in the same way since it is often inefficient for it to do so.

Comment: Ya true Strings are treated differently but substring method will have a reference to original string right.?? so will not prevent Original String sample for being garbage collected .

Comment: I am aware of no reason `substring` would hold a reference to the original object; it is a function, not a first-class object. What it returns can be considered independent of the original object. Is there a deeper concern here that would elucidate what you're getting at?