# Confusion about String substring method

Tags: java

I have a question. I was reading in a blog about substring.Quoting it below.

> One point which is worth remembering here is that substring is also
>   backed up by character array, which is used by original String. This
>   can be dangerous if original string object is very large and substring
>   is very small, because even a small fraction can hold reference of
>   complete array and prevents it from being garbage collected even if
>   there is no other reference for that particular String

I am not able to understand what does it mean to say a small reference can prevent from garbage collection. Can someone explain this concept? Thanks

Comment: I believe this should answer your question: [Will a substring of another string prevent the parent string from being garbage collected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857883/will-a-substring-of-another-string-prevent-the-parent-string-from-being-garbage)

Comment: FYI, this is no longer true in Oracle Java 7 as the backing `char[]` is no longer shared.

Comment: You can refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514349/lost-string-garbage-collection.

Comment: Sotirios can you explain. Why in java 7 it is removed

Comment: @benz You can look at my comment in Oscar's answer. It was removed in part for the reasons in your quote.

Answer (score 3):

It means that all new strings created as a result of a `substring()` operation hold a reference to the character array in  the original string, and the original character array won't be garbage collected until all the substrings derived from it are also garbage collected, no matter if they're big or small.

As pointed out in the comments, this situation doesn't arise in recent versions of Java (1.7.0_06 and newer). See this [link](http://java-performance.info/changes-to-string-java-1-7-0_06/) for an explanation, but in short: nowadays `substring()` creates a new string each time, so the underlying `char[]` doesn't get shared anymore.

Comment: In Oracle Java 7, this is no longer true.

Comment: Oh I understand the concept now. I was so confused about the terminology. I understand now.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis can you provide a link stating this, please?

Comment: This [link](http://java-performance.info/changes-to-string-java-1-7-0_06/) explains it and you can look at the `String` source code.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis good call! thanks :)

Comment: Sotirios thanks a ton great article. Made the concept completely clear now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this link answers your question:

[Will a substring of another string prevent the parent string from being garbage collected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857883/will-a-substring-of-another-string-prevent-the-parent-string-from-being-garbage)

```
// Example 1
String samplel = "ToBeGarbageCollected";
String sample2 = samplel.substring(0, 1);

// Example 2
String samplel = "ToBeGarbageCollected";
String sample2 = new String(samplel.substring(0, 1));
```

> The substring method doesn't put a reference to the original String in
>   the new String. What it actually does is save a reference to the
>   original String's backing array; i.e the array that holds the
>   characters.
>
> ... The original String's entire backing array will be remain reachable
>   ... and that means it won't be a candidate for garbage collection.
>
> But there is another complication. You set sample1 to a String
>   literal, and the String object that represents a String literal is
>   always reachable (unless the entire class gets unloaded!)
>
> In your second example, copying the substring causes a new String to
>   be created. And it is guaranteed that the new String won't share the
>   backing array with the original String and the temporary substring

ALSO:

As Sotirios Delimanolis correctly says: this is no longer true of Java 7 or higher:

[Java 7 String - substring complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123446/java-7-string-substring-complexity)